# Load existing sqlite database and run in chrome browser in ionic

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework, cordova-plugin-file

I have an existing database named 'test.db' in www/. I embedded the database to work in android device by using cordova file plugin to transfer the file to the correct path in android as following.

```
$cordovaFile.copyFile(cordova.file.applicationDirectory + 'www/', "test.db", cordova.file.dataDirectory, "test.db")
    .then(function (success) {
      console.log('success');
      db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "test.db"});
    }, function (error) {
      console.log('error file transfer : ', error);
    });
```

It works in android device. However, I would like to run this in browser for quick developing the application by command (ionic serve). Please kindly tell me how to embed the sqlite database and run in browser.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I came across an article, and I thought I'd add a link here in case it applies:
https://www.techiediaries.com/mocking-native-sqlite-plugin/